# Error when calling 'transform' method in Collaborative filtering recommender in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm trying to evaluate my recommender model, but when I call transform function for my model I've got this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'MatrixFactorizationModel' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

I'm using Pyspark 2.4.3 and In Documentation, this method is mentioned.
You can see Pyspark 2.4.3 Documentation in here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/ml-collaborative-filtering.html

This is my code for train model and use of transform function:

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator

(train_df, test_df) = df.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])
model = ALS.train(train_df, rank = 5, iterations = 10, seed = 123, lambda_ = 0.012)

predictions = model.transform(test_df)
```

Anyone can help me with this problem!??

Comment: you messed up the ML and MLlib libraries, the document you pointed to is for ML library while you are trying to initialize ALS model with MLlib and then use a method of ML library.

Comment: In this case just import the things using the ml package, not mllib